# Motherboard with FSB faster than RAM support?

Tags: memory, cpu, performance, motherboard, clockspeed

now I'm struggling to understand how and why is it possible to have a motherboard with higher clock speed for FSB (800/1066/1333 MHz) and supporting only a DDR2 architecture with a maximum of (800 Mhz)
Is that no sense? or the CPU (1333 MHz) is actually benefited by this architecture.

The specs:

- Asus IPIBL-LB-Benicia-GL8E FSB (800/1066/1333 MHz)
- Intel Core 2 Quad Q9650 (1333 MHz)
- RAM DDR2 (800 Mhz)

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Fsb changes the CPU clock

Comment: Am I right at thinking that it all runs at 800 Mhz?

Comment: Runs at whichever the memory is suppose to run at it